# how can I write for loop in python for copy pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm newbie in data engineer. now i try to write python code for duplicate data from from pandas dataframe. for example
data :

```
       A B C D E F G E
       1 2 3 4 0 1 0 1
       5 6 7 8 0 1 1 0
       9 1 2 3 0 1 0 1
```

I need to copy dataframe to

```
dfE =  A B C D E 
       1 2 3 4 0 
       5 6 7 8 0 
       9 1 2 3 0
dfF =  A B C D F 
       1 2 3 4 1 
       5 6 7 8 1 
       9 1 2 3 1
dfG...
```

Help me please...

Comment: why do you have two  `E` column?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake,It's just example.

Answer (score 0):

Hi piyaphong welcome to stackoverflow,

Basically pandas allow to select columns with column names, you can look at the code below which would probably solve your case.

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

data = """
A B C D E F G E
1 2 3 4 0 1 0 1
5 6 7 8 0 1 1 0
9 1 2 3 0 1 0 1
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=' ')

dfE = df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']]
dfF = df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F']]
dfG = df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'G']]
```

Comment: Thank you.But I have very more column(more than 50) . Are you have different way?